# Android ActionBarSherlock On Top Icon Back

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, back

I'm trying to make my top action bar icon to allow users to go back to previous screen. I tried to implement these codes. But none are working. Can anyone please guide me on this. I know this looks simple, I'm new to android . Below are my codes.

Problem : When i tap on the icon button it just cleared my screen without going to the previous screen.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_item);
        checkInternetConnection();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //<--THIS




@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{    
   switch (item.getItemId()) 
   {        
      case android.R.id.home:            
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, SingleViewActivity.class);            
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME); 
         startActivity(intent);            
         return true;        
      default:            
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the way I do it:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, main.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I just use finish() to return back.

Answer (score 2):

In your ressources(res)
go to menu 
and add 
this make sur u have some button back for in your drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:icon="@drawable/back1"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="back"/>
```

now in your activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        break;
    case R.id.back:
        Intent in = new Intent(this, <classname which you want to go back>.class);
        startActivity(in);
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try this code

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:icon="@drawable/btn_back"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="@string/txt_back"/>
```

>

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case R.id.back:
                back_action();
            return true;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

>